# python - assert somehow immediately detects infinite recursion

Tags: python, recursion, try-catch, infinite-loop, assert

I wrote a fibonacci function that infinitely recurses, and while python couldn't detect it and threw errors upon hitting the max recursion limit, when I used try and assert to see if fib(30) was equal to some value, it immediately told me it was not. How did it do this? It seems like it didn't even need to run fib(30).

note:
I realize this only works if I do

```
try:
    assert infiniteFib(30) == 832040
except:
    print "done immediately"
```

When I do just the assert, it produces many errors about too many recursions, but with the try it stops at the first error.

What I'm curious is how does python manage to produce an error so quickly about infinite recursion? Wouldn't it need to hit the limit (which takes a long time) to tell whether it was infinite?

EDIT:
Some requested code, but just to be clear, I DON'T want a solution to the errors (I know it's wrong because I deliberately excluded the base case), I want to know how python produces errors so quickly when it should take much longer (if you do `fib(30)`, clearly it takes a while to hit the max recursion limit, but somehow python produces errors way before then):

```
def fib(n):
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

try: assert(fib(30) == 832040)
except: print "done immediately"
```

Comment: can you share your code with current progress?

Comment: Unless you add the code for your fib() function and show us the details of error, it would be difficult to tell what's wrong.

Comment: I added the code, as requested, but I don't want a solution to how to make the code work, I just want to know how python makes its infinite recursion errors so quickly, prior to even reaching the max recursion limit.

Comment: Did you try adding a print-statement to the `fib`-function? Maybe it is actually recursing until the max depth, it's just too fast for you to notice (it really shouldn't take too long).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not done immediately. Your code runs until python reaches maximum recursion depth and [maximum recursion depth](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) is set to 1000 by default in python to avoid stack overflow errors.

So, actually your code runs till it reaches recursion depth of 1000 and errors out `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. You can verify this by modifying your code as below:

```
i=0
def fib(n):
    global i
    i = i + 1
    print i
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

assert(fib(30) == 832040)
print i
print "done immediately"
```

In my machine, i am getting the last `i` value as 984 before errors out.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the code you've shown runs quickly is because it catches the exception that is raised by `fib` when it hits the recursion limit and doesn't print the traceback. Running to the recursion limit doesn't take very long at all, but formatting and printing hundreds of lines of traceback does.

If you inspect the exception you get, you'll see it is the same `RuntimeError` you get when you run `fib` normally, not an `AssertionError`. Try this, to see what is going on better:

```
try:
    assert(fib(30) == 832040)
except Exception as e:
    print("Got an Exception: %r" % e)
```